# How cpu works in conky

Tags: arch-linux, cpu, conky

I' m trying to setup conky and I saw that I can use from cpu0 to cpu4

```
CPU0 ${cpu cpu0}% ${cpubar cpu0}
CPU1 ${cpu cpu1}% ${cpubar cpu1}
CPU2 ${cpu cpu2}% ${cpubar cpu2}
CPU3 ${cpu cpu3}% ${cpubar cpu3}
CPU4 ${cpu cpu4}% ${cpubar cpu4}
```

Why I have 5 cpu % if I go over cpu4, example:

```
CPU5 ${cpu cpu5}% ${cpubar cpu5}
```

It doesn' t show any % ??

I have an Intel i5, so I suppose that is a quad-core, right?
CPU0 what shows?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`cpu0` is the average load, `cpuN` (where `N` >=1) is the load only on the Nth Cpu.

Excerpt from [conky objects](http://conky.sourceforge.net/variables.html)

> CPU usage in percents. For SMP machines, the CPU number can be
>   provided as an argument. ${cpu cpu0} is the total usage, and ${cpu
>   cpuX} (X >= 1) are individual CPUs.

Comment: Thank you, very helpful. But CPU0 doesn't show the sum, because CPU1 is 11%, CPU2 is 9%, CPU3 is 3% and CPU4 2% at the moment and CPU0 shows 6%. So maybe is Media, right?

Comment: Well it is the total usage across all cpus, so it is actually the average.

Answer (score -2):

Probably CPU0 or CPU4 shows summed load.

Comment: Saying 'probably' without doing research isn't a helpful answer, this could be better placed in a comment.